# Pass native dom elements to vue application and render

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to pass native DOM elements (rendered server-side) to a vue application?

Simple markup:

```
<div class="c-search"></div>
```

Will be "mounted" to a vue application by:

```
new Vue({
  render: (h) =>
    h(NameOfTheComponent),
  }).$mount(document.querySelector('.c-search'););
```

So far, so good. But what if I want dom elements inside this html container to be passed to the application and render e.g. in a slot?

Markup:

```
<div class="c-search">
  <div class="c-search__disclaimer">
    <h1>This disclaimer text is rendered from a cms and should be rendered within the vue application</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, I pass the div as a prop and render it by v-html, but this is vulnerable and not recommended by the vue documentation. Is there a way to access child nodes of the application wrapper and re-render?

Comment: AFAIK it works best if the backend is an API and the frontend implements it, so they stay independant of each other. Injecting elements which need to be eval'd or parsed can become a problem long-term anyway. Or maybe you are looking for [inertiaJS](https://inertiajs.com/)?

Comment: This is not a slot so it cannot be used like one. You can just get innerHtml and use it with v-html or compile it with Vue compiler. "this is vulnerable and not recommended by the vue documentation" - it's vulnerable any way. If you can't guarantee this HTML to be safe, don't use it or at least sanitize it.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answers. At this time, I will stick with passing as props and render by v-html, as it will be a bit overhead to develop an api and fetch on demand for a single disclaimer sentence.